# Android: How to switch theme for dark mode?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

Since Android 10, you can switch between dark mode and default light mode. I didn't make any closer research yet on this since it's a new topic. Is Dark mode color switching automatic by OS or is there any way to tell my App to switch different app-theme if Dark mode is turned on?  Also dark mode is possibility for some Android 9 devices.

Because I made custom Dark theme with custom parameters and I set dark color for each of my color in resources (using custom attributes in `attrs.xml` and applied specific color resource to them inside theme in `styles.xml`). Same it is working for different color schemes of my App (blue, red, green for example). That way I can tell which color would be used for different views in my App and not system.

Only thing I need is to detect if dark mode is on/off in system. I can force user to turn on Dark mode in App settings (custom settings) but theme can be affected by system dark mode (turned on in Phone settings).

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134005/how-to-automatically-switch-to-dark-mode-on-android-app/59134396#59134396)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [official documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#supporting_dark_theme_in_your_app):

> In order to support Dark theme, you must set your app's theme (usually found in res/values/styles.xml) to inherit from a DayNight theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

> You can also use MaterialComponents' dark theming:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

> This ties the app's main theme to the system-controlled night mode flags and gives the app a default Dark theme (when it is enabled).

It means that if you use a DayNight theme, the OS itself handles the app theme. if you want to force app uses dark theme check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#changing_themes_in-app) documentation.

### UPDATE:

To detect the device theme:

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        …
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        …
        break; 
}
```

Comment: Will try this. Because as I mentioned, if I have 5 different color variations of my App, I have to make 5 different dark themes for them. That means I have to pick which color theme based on which light theme is currently used by App.

Comment: @martin1337 Check the updated answer. You can detect device theme and base on that, set your app theme.

Comment: It is working fine with `and` operator instead of & inside when(). And I also tested it on Android 10 virtual device. I should call this code in onResume I suppose, because my theme did not switched only after app restart.

Comment: @martin1337 No. you need to set night mode in application class. Check a_local_nobody comment on the question.