# android, how to use MaterialCardView while using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-night-mode, materialcardview

The app is using androidX with minSdk 21, and using

`AppCompatActivity` with theme:

```
<style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

for the AppCompat DayNight theme, and switching day or night theme like:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) // or AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
```

But when uses `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`
  (with `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`)

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/myCardViewStyle"
        ...>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

...

  <style name="CustomCardViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
     <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_custom_corners</item>
  </style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_custom_corners" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

it got crash:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #573: Binary XML file line #573: 
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
```

What could be the cause?
If using MaterialCardView, what theme should use and still be able to do

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

Note:

In the [Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md),
it says `Change your app theme to inherit from a Material Components theme`, and

```
Material Components themes
The following is the list of Material Components themes you can use to get the latest component styles and theme-level attributes.

Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
Update your app theme to inherit from one of these themes, e.g.:

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

I saw the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` used in the app is in derive chain eventually back up to `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
<style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.AppCompat.Light">
<style name="Platform.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.V21.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="Platform.V21.AppCompat.Light" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and the `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` is deprived from `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: You have to use a Theme.MaterialComponents.* theme

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280176/12546733

Answer (score 3):

Try using this in your MaterialCardView?

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

Adding this in your MaterialCardView will not affect your app theme I believe.