# Switch light/day/night theme on Android App on runtime

Tags: android

When the phone set to dark mode.

But user want to choose theme (day/night) only on this app.

Any idea to programmatically change app theme on run time?

Comment: does this help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134005/how-to-automatically-switch-to-dark-mode-on-android-app/59134396#59134396

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to change it

```java
    //Turn on night mode
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    //Turn off night mode
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

I applied it in an app using a switch like this

```java
Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                }else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add uiMode configuration change:

In AndroidManifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```

Use this code to force light/day mode also need to recreate the activity

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
recreate()
```

Use this code to force dark/night mode also need to recreate the activity

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
recreate()
```

To be realistic this Kotlin code work fine for me (should add theme by system default too)

```
val currentNightMode =
            resources.getConfiguration().uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
        when (currentNightMode) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                if (getAppSetting(
                        getString(R.string.key_setting_theme),
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
                    ) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
                )
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                recreate()
            } // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                if (getAppSetting(
                        getString(R.string.key_setting_theme),
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
                    ) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO
                )
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                recreate()
            } // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
        }
```

There are more option

```
MODE_NIGHT_NO. Always use the day (light) theme.
MODE_NIGHT_YES. Always use the night (dark) theme.
MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM (default). This setting follows the system’s setting, which on Android Q and above is a system setting (more on this below).
MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY. Changes to dark when the device has its ‘Battery Saver’ feature enabled, light otherwise.
MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME & MODE_NIGHT_AUTO. Changes between day/night based on the time of day.
```

for more info
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Comment: According to [this section](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#change-themes) *Starting with AppCompat v1.1.0, setDefaultNightMode() automatically recreates any started activities.*
So no need to use `recreate()`